# GeoCoder cuauses java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3

Tags: java, android, google-maps

hi guys i am working with geocoder for getting latitude and longitude but my code work well sometimes otherwise it through exception which is

```html
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 3, size is 3
            at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
            at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
            at com.example.mine4.latitudelongitudeconverter.LatLangToLoCaTion$1.onClick(LatLangToLoCaTion.java:70)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17620)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

now the problem I can't understand.The code I am using for that is

```html
final int maxResult =5;
    String addressList[] = new String[maxResult];

try {
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, maxResult);

                    if(addresses != null) {

                        for (int j=0; j<maxResult; j++){
                            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(j);
                            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder();
                            for(int i=0; i<returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                            }
                            addressList[j] = strReturnedAddress.toString();
                        }

                        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
                                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, addressList);
                        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.
                                simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        myAddressList.setAdapter(adapter);

                        myAddressList.setOnItemSelectedListener(myAddressListOnItemSelectedListener);
                    }
```

Now Please hlp me to find out the real problem. Here One thing I wanna tell you that I am getting latitude and longitude through EditText from user
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I guess `maxResult` should be equal to `addresses.size()` and not 5

Answer (score 0):

It means you are passing Invalid `index 3`, when `size` is `3`, basically index starting from 0 so you can able to pass `0,1,2` index to fetch value from array or list when its size is 3. now when you passing index 3 indicates  `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, you could not pass index more than its size.To get 3 Index values `Array` or `List` size should be `4` or more.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you j becomes 3 and the size is 3, hence it breaks when inside the for loop